# Forward any subdomain to single server

Tags: domain-name-system, nginx

Having site `example.com`

How can I configure Nginx zone file that every subdomain like test.example.com and so on would be forwarded to one server.

Problem is that I do not know in advance possible subdomains so I can not list them by hand.

Comment: What "forwarded to one server mean"? Do they should be redirected?

Answer (score 2):

You define a default server block:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;

    return 301 http://example.com;
}
```

This affects every domain on the server, not just subdomains of a selected server. You cannot restrict this to particular subdomains without enumerating all those domains.

Comment: `server_name _;` is old and redundant. But you could remove `default_server` and use `server_name *.example.com` to match only subdomains. Though I'm not sure what author meant by "forwarded to one server"

Answer (score 0):

server_name _; and default_server on the listen configuration are what you are looking for.

server {

listen 80 default_server;
   server_name _;

root /var/www/default; (or wherever)

}